# What conditions are needed for this statement to be true and why?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

In the summary of the lectures, appears the sentence:
"Given a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, 
then $x_0$ is a local maximum of $f$ if and only if, for every $0\neq v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, t=0 is a local maximum of $g(t)=f(x_0+tv)$".
As it is, the statement isn't true. For example: 
$f(x, y)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if }\;  y=x^2, x>0 \\ 
0 & \text{ else } 
\end{cases}$

But are there any conditions that make the statement true? (Such as continuity in a neighborhood of $x_0$, diffrentiability etc.)

The reason I'm asking the question is related to a chapter that talks about the Hessian matrix. I just can't understand how it is used to determine min/max.
I'd be very thankful if someone could send me a link to a good explanation.

Thank you!

Comment: It uses *Taylor's formula* at order 2, and is a translation of a certain quadratic form being definite negative. For functions of one variable, it is the second derivative test for local extrema.

Comment: Taylor hasn't been discussed yet

Comment: I beg your pardon, but why do they speak of the hessian then?

Comment: That's the order in the lectures... First they talk about how the hessian is used to determine if a point is min/max/saddle (which I don't understand because of the false statement above), and only then they talk about taylor (but I haven't reached that yet).

Comment: Well they give the rules, and justify them later. The false statement above has nothing to see with the hessian, since the example above corresponds to a discontinuity.

Comment: Just a question of notations: do you define local maximum with strict inequality or not? Because if you assume non-strict inequalities, in your counterexample the point $(0,0)$ is a  local  maximum, and the statement in question holds.

Comment: Can you explain why the statement holds if the inequality is strict? Maybe that's what they meant